# Is the use of a <br/> tag between a <label> and its <input> good practice?

Tags: html, css, forms, semantics

The fields in my form have a label, some help text, some example text, and some contextual text.

```
<!--With Help and Example-->
<li>
    <label for="ingredients">Ingredients</label>
    <br/><!--Is this good practice?-->
    <span class="help">Enter one ingredient per line.</span>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="ingredients" name="ingredients"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <span class="example"><b>Example:</b><br/>1 Cup of Flour<br/>Pinch of Salt<br/>1 Tbsp of Paprika</span>

<!--With context-->
<li>
   <label for="yield">Yield</label>
   <br /> <!--Wish labels were block and you had to style them to be inline-->
   <input type="number" id="yield" name="yield" />
   <span class="context"> servings.</span>
</li>
```

When I look at it un-styled it drives me nuts how all of these things run together on the same line.

I might have come up with a solution to my question while typing. I think I might use `<p>` for my help and example text. I still don't like that labels are always on the same line as the input.

Comment: Your use of `<b>` is absolutely bad HTML.

Comment: Why's that? I don't want any emphasis placed on the text it contains. I just want it typographically/visually bold. In other words. If I left it out and didn't make the text bold it would still make total sense. 

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_b.asp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If one is being really pedantic, almost all uses of `<br/>` are 'bad HTML'. `<br/>` means a semantic line break. In other words, where removing the `<br/>` would change the meaning of the content. These really only occur in poetry/lyrics and postal addresses.

You could achieve the same outcome by making the other elements inside the `<li>`s have display:block styling.

Comment: Thanks. I was over-thinking it. I was planning on styling them as block. While I was writing the HTML, I kept looking at it all running together on one line, in my browser. I couldn't help but want to break the lines.

Answer (score 4):

It's not bad per se, but you ought to use CSS for styling (e.g. layout). It makes the code easier to read. E.g.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
  #myrecipies label,
  #myrecipies li:first-child span:first-child,
  #myrecipies textarea {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myrecipies">
  <li>
    <label for="ingredients">Ingredients</label>
    <span class="help">Enter one ingredient per line.</span>
    <textarea id="ingredients" name="ingredients"></textarea>
    <span class="example"><b>Example:</b><br/>1 Cup of Flour<br/>Pinch of Salt<br/>1 Tbsp of Paprika</span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <label for="yield">Yield</label>
   <input type="number" id="yield" name="yield" />
   <span class="context"> servings.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This [code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/e4ujN/).

Answer (score 3):

If you mean "bad" as in invalid, according to the W3 validator, no. `<br>`s are allowed between `<label>` and `<input>` elements.

Comment: Actually, `<br>` elements are allowed inside `<li>` elements. Its siblings are completely irrelevant.

Comment: I know that it's valid. I guess what I'm wondering is whether or not it's good practice. I may be over-thinking the issue.

Answer (score 3):

"Bad" as in invalid? No.
"Bad" as in unsemantic? Yes.

A better way of doing this would be to wrap your `label` elements in `p` elements. They are paragraphs, after all. (Besides, labels are not something that *should* be block elements, it is an inline element because it gives *purpose* to inline text, the same way `em` or the HTML5 `time` element does — a block element does more than that. Style it as a block element using CSS)

**Edit:** See also the answer by Alohci, explaining why `<br>` is being used incorrectly here.

Comment: Wrapping a label in a paragraph? That's no better than using a line break.  Most form labels aren't paragraphs of text, so they don't belong in a `<p>` tag.

Comment: A "paragraph" doesn't have to be more than a few words long, it merely describes a block of text.

Comment: No, in writing, a paragraph typically contains one or more sentences (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph) and deals with a single point or idea.  Since the W3C spec says that the `<p>` tag indicates a paragraph of text (http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1), a form label is an inappropriate use of the `<p>` element.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a lable needs to be in the same line as the input field.
The only thing that is important for a good user experience, is that it is next to it, which could also mean above.